# Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers when running sklearn GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I am running a GridSearchCV on different models using GridSearchCV using the following code:

```
def algorithm_pipeline(X_train_data, X_test_data, y_train_data, y_test_data,
                       model, param_grid, cv=10, scoring_fit='accuracy',
                       scoring_test=roc_auc_score, do_probabilities = True):
    gs = GridSearchCV(
        estimator=model,
        param_grid=param_grid,
        cv=cv,
        n_jobs=-1,
        scoring=scoring_fit,
        verbose=2
    )
    fitted_model = gs.fit(X_train_data, y_train_data)
    best_model = fitted_model.best_estimator_

    if do_probabilities:
      pred = fitted_model.predict_proba(X_test_data)
    else:
      pred = fitted_model.predict(X_test_data)

    score = scoring_test(y_test_data, pred)

    return [best_model, score]


models_to_train = [LogisticRegression(),XGBClassifier(), RandomForestClassifier()]
grid_parameters = [
    {   # Logistic Regression
        'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
        'penalty':['none', 'elasticnet', 'l1', 'l2'],
        'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
    },
    {  # XGBoost
        'n_estimators': [400, 700, 1000],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.7, 0.8],
        'max_depth': [15,20],
        'reg_alpha': [1.1, 1.3],
        'reg_lambda': [1.1, 1.3],
        'subsample': [0.7, 0.9]
    },
    { # Random Forest Classifier
        'n_estimators': [200, 500],
        'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
        'max_depth' : [4,6,8],
        'criterion' :['gini', 'entropy']
}
]
models_preds_scores = []

with tqdm(total=len(models_to_train)) as pbar:
    for i, model in enumerate(models_to_train):
        pbar.update(1)
        params = grid_parameters[i]
    
        result = algorithm_pipeline(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,
                                     model, params, cv=5)
        models_preds_scores.append(result)
```

However, everytime it finishes running the first model, it returns the following error:

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 159, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 215, in dumps
    dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol)
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 208, in dump
    _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 632, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py", line 446, in __call__
    for dumped_filename in dump(a, filename):
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 553, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/usr/local/sas/grid/python3-prod/lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 487, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 352, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 134, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tobytes('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/MAIN_DIR/prediction_tuning/crypto_prediction.py", line 78, in <module>
    result = algorithm_pipeline(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scratch/MAIN_DIR/prediction_tuning/crypto_prediction.py", line 38, in algorithm_pipeline
    fitted_model = gs.fit(X_train_data, y_train_data)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1474, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 970, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1527, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 916, in evaluate_candidates
    out = parallel(
          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 67, in __call__
    return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1952, in __call__
    return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1595, in _get_outputs
    yield from self._retrieve()
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1699, in _retrieve
    self._raise_error_fast()
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1734, in _raise_error_fast
    error_job.get_result(self.timeout)
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 736, in get_result
    return self._return_or_raise()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/DIR/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 754, in _return_or_raise
    raise self._result
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

I thought it was a problem about not having enough memory, so I allocated more RAM to the job (48GB), or having more RAM allocated to each core. But the results are the same. I do not know where the problem lies.